C opendir, readdir erorr: free(): invalid size, Aborted (core dumped)
I have the following code to cycle through the numeric dirs inside /proc and get the names of the folders by going further into the dir of the given PID:
/proc/PID/cmdline

This is the C code:
  char* getNameByPID(const char* cmdline_CmdLinePath, const int PID){
      char* chrptr_NameOfProcess;
      FILE* fd_CmdLineFile = fopen (cmdline_CmdLinePath, "rt") ;  // open the file for reading text if (fd_CmdLineFile) {
      if (fd_CmdLineFile) {
          chrptr_NameOfProcess = malloc(200);
          if (fscanf(fd_CmdLineFile, "%s", chrptr_NameOfProcess) != 1) {
              free(chrptr_NameOfProcess);
              chrptr_NameOfProcess = NULL;
          }
          fclose(fd_CmdLineFile);
      }   
      return chrptr_NameOfProcess;
  }       
          
  void printInfo(int intHasArgs) {
      DIR* dir_proc = NULL;
      dir_proc = opendir(PROC_DIRECTORY);
          
      if (dir_proc == NULL) {
          perror("Couldn't open the " PROC_DIRECTORY " directory");
      }   
          
      struct dirent* de_DirEntity = NULL;                                                                                                                                                     
      char smaps_CmdLinePath[100];
      char cmdline_CmdLinePath[100];
          
      while ( (de_DirEntity = readdir(dir_proc)) ) {
          if ( de_DirEntity->d_type == DT_DIR ) {
              if ( isNumeric(de_DirEntity->d_name) ) {
                  strcpy(smaps_CmdLinePath, PROC_DIRECTORY);
                  strcpy(cmdline_CmdLinePath, PROC_DIRECTORY);
                  strcat(smaps_CmdLinePath, de_DirEntity->d_name);
                  strcat(cmdline_CmdLinePath, de_DirEntity->d_name);
                  strcat(smaps_CmdLinePath, "/smaps");
                  strcat(cmdline_CmdLinePath, "/cmdline");
                  char* procName = getNameByPID(cmdline_CmdLinePath, atoi(de_DirEntity->d_name));
                  if (procName != NULL && procName[0] != '\0') {
                      printf("%s\n", procName);
                  }
              }
          }
      }   
      closedir(dir_proc) ;
  }

It works as expected (printing the names of all the numeric dirs found), but at the end it prints:
free(): invalid size
Aborted (core dumped)

which tells me there's some memory leakage, but I did add a check and free memory if the initial malloc was unsuccessful:
if (fscanf(fd_CmdLineFile, "%s", chrptr_NameOfProcess) != 1) {
                  free(chrptr_NameOfProcess);
                  chrptr_NameOfProcess = NULL;
}

I tried also adding the following:
if (procName != NULL && procName[0] != '\0') {
    printf("%s\n", procName);
    free(procName);
}

but this didn't help the issue either.

return chrptr_NameOfProcess; returns an uninitialized pointer if fopen() failed. You should initialize it to NULL.

If opendir() returns NULL you log an error and try to process the directory anyway.

Instead of all those strcpy() and strcat() calls, use sprintf(cmdline_CmdLinePath, "%s%s/cmdline", PROC_DIRECTORY, de_DirEntity->d_name)

And free(): invalid size Aborted (core dumped)
doesn't tell you anything about memory leakage.  It tell you that you corrupted your heap somehow.

You do have memory leakage, though. You never free procName.

You are almost certainly abusing memory, writing out of bounds or at an invalid address.  Can you use Valgrind?  If so, do so — it will probably tell you where the problem is almost immediately.  Just make sure you're testing a debug build of the code.  There are other memory sanity checkers if Valgrind is not available — it varies by platform.

Thank you for all the tips, I'll definitely look into Valgrind and add a check to see if fopens and opendir was a success. Really appreciate all the advice from everyone, wish I could @ more than one user

FINAL UPDATE:
thanks to the feedback and suggestion to use Valgrind, I made the following changes:
char* getNameByPID(const char* cmdline_CmdLinePath, const int PID){
    char* chrptr_NameOfProcess = NULL;
    FILE* fd_CmdLineFile = fopen (cmdline_CmdLinePath, "rt") ;  // open the file for reading text if (fd_CmdLineFile) {

    if ( fd_CmdLineFile )
    {
        chrptr_NameOfProcess = malloc(500);
        int result = fscanf(fd_CmdLineFile, "%s", chrptr_NameOfProcess);
        fclose( fd_CmdLineFile );

        if ( result == 1 ) {
            return chrptr_NameOfProcess;
        } else {
            free(chrptr_NameOfProcess);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    fclose( fd_CmdLineFile );

    return NULL;
}

int printInfo(int intHasArgs) {
    DIR* dir_proc = NULL;
    dir_proc = opendir(PROC_DIRECTORY);

    if (dir_proc == NULL) {
        perror("Couldn't open the " PROC_DIRECTORY " directory");
        return 1;
    }

    struct dirent* de_DirEntity = NULL;
    size_t procDirLen = strlen(PROC_DIRECTORY);
    size_t cmdLineLen = strlen("/cmdline");
    size_t smapsLen   = strlen("/smaps");
    // char* smaps_CmdLinePath;
    char cmdline_CmdLinePath[300];

    while ( (de_DirEntity = readdir(dir_proc)) ) {
        if ( de_DirEntity->d_type == DT_DIR ) {
            if ( isNumeric(de_DirEntity->d_name) ) {
                // smaps_CmdLinePath = malloc(procDirLen + smapsLen + strlen(de_DirEntity->d_name));
                sprintf(cmdline_CmdLinePath, "%s%s/cmdline", PROC_DIRECTORY, de_DirEntity->d_name);
                // sprintf(smaps_CmdLinePath, "%s%s/smaps", PROC_DIRECTORY, de_DirEntity->d_name);
                char* procName = getNameByPID(cmdline_CmdLinePath, atoi(de_DirEntity->d_name));
                if (procName != NULL && procName[0] != '\0') {
                    printf("%s\n", procName);
                }
                free(procName);
                // free(smaps_CmdLinePath);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir_proc) ;
    return 0;
}

the error:
free(): invalid size
Aborted (core dumped)

is now gone and I think the error appeared initially because my char array for the filepaths (cmdline_CmdLinePath) was too small.
I bumped it up to 300 because sprintf was showing it was writing approx 270 bytes sometimes. In addition, I increased the malloc to 500 and I think I'll leave it add that since I'm not editing the process names to remove dashes which leave me with procs like the following:
/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1

that could get rather long. Thanks for the help!
Note - if any improvements can be made to the above code regardless if it does the job, please let me know!

Looks like you're writing past the end of allocated memory.  Make sure you compile with -g so valgrind will report the line numbers in your code.

that would've super helpful haha, but I'm not seeing the -g flag in valgrind --help, weird

It's a gcc flag, not a valgrind flag.
